# Local Communication - 127.0.0.1 vs. IPC

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipc

I am not clearly understanding the difference between using TCP socket with client connecting to 127.0.0.1 server address and other IPC such as message queues. Since both are used for communication within the same host, why at all someone would go for socket approach leaving the message queue one, as in this case, sockets will cause more overhead compared to the queues.

The differences that I am seeing:-
In case of sockets we can see the contents in wireshark, in queues there is no such way.

Comment: user9071725 - This question is what is considered "overbroad" on SO.   Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) for the comparison of various approaches. TCP goes over the network stack, so Wireshark can monitor it.

Comment: An example of TCP usage over the normal IPC functionality would be very helpful. You could base your question on that example and ask about that specific case you show us.

Comment: One advantage of using TCP is that maybe in the future you want the other process on another machine. TCP - this is easy to do.

Comment: 'I want to go from address A in city B to address C in city D.  Should I drive, take the train or fly?'   Too broad:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP and IPC both approach we use for inter process communication in distributed architecture. If processes are running in same machine we will go for message queue but surely not TCP. But suppose one application is running in one box and another application is running in a different box definitely we have to go for TCP for inter process communication. Even web services also internally implement TCP for communicating to a remote application.

But still we need a TCP base communication in the same machine between two process where synchronize communication is must. For example if you send a request for an account information of a client and waiting for the response you need this approach. But if you just need to send a client information to a server to store it in a table and you don't need an answer from  that server whether your records has been stored successfully or not you just go for a queue only to drop the message.

Comment: 127.0.0.1/8 is an address space that refers to the local machine. The question is, why anyone would prefer TCP over the usual kernel-provided IPC in this *self-referencing* case.

Comment: @Downvoter, I have modified my answer. We do require TCP communication based on requirement. Even in my server TCP communication is there between two process for synchronize communication and in the same server we use IBM message queue for asynchronous communication. Thanks for you comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

The point of the loopback interface / address is not that you write programs to use it specifically.

The point is that it lets you talk to network services running on the local computer in the *same way* that you would talk to network services running on a remote host.  For instance, if I'm developing a website, I can start up a test instance of its server on my local computer and then point my browser at `http://127.0.0.1/` and there it is.  I don't have to modify the code of my browser to talk over AF_UNIX sockets or whatever first.  Similarly, if I am writing an application that needs a database, I might start out with the database running on the same computer as the application, talking to it over loopback, but then later when the database gets bigger I can move it to a dedicated host and I don't have to change anything other than the connection configuration.

You are absolutely correct that local IPC has lower overhead, and should be used when the two processes that need to communicate will *always* be on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit Pritam. I got it. Well Explained.